# target href in section MAIN

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am developing a web application and I am having a problem with a menu in the header.
I explain better:
my page is divided like this:

```
<div>
   <header>
      <font color=white align='center'>HEADER</font>
      <nav class='clearfix'>
          <ul class='clearfix'>
              <li><a id='home' href='#'>Home</a></li>
              <li><a id='pagina1' href='#'>pagina1</a></li>
              <li><a id='pagina2' href='#'>pagina2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href='#' id='pull'>Menu</a>
      </nav>
   </header>
</div>
<main>
    <h1> Main</h1>
</main>

<footer>
    <nav class='clearfix'>
    <font color=white align='center'>FOOTER</font>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

And obviously I have other pages like pagina1.php and pagina2.php

Now....I would like to load the pagina1.php in the  when I click on the button on the menu.

I tried some scripts but it seems not not working...Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified a location for the link to go to. href='#' will keep you on the same page. Change this to any other url.

for example

```
<li><a id='home' href='/home.php'>Home</a></li>
<li><a id='pagina1' href='/pagina1.php'>/pagina1</a></li>
<li><a id='pagina2' href='/pagina2.php'>/pagina2/a></li>
```

EDIT: 
Since your recent comment indicates you want to change the content of main when you click on a link, this should do the trick.

- Create a page called pagina1.html (or php, does not matter) and add the following content:

  Pagina1
- Create a page called pagina2.html (or php, does not matter) and add the following content:

  Pagina 2

Modify your existing page to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#pagina1").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"pagina1.html",success:function(result){
      $("#main").html(result);
    }});
  });

  $("#pagina2").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"pagina2.html",success:function(result){
      $("#main").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<div>
   <header>
      <font color=white align='center'>HEADER</font>
      <nav class='clearfix'>
          <ul class='clearfix'>
              <li><a id='home' href='#'>Home</a></li>
              <li><a id='pagina1' href='#'>pagina1</a></li>
              <li><a id='pagina2' href='#'>pagina2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href='#' id='pull'>Menu</a>
      </nav>
   </header>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <h1> Main</h1>
</div>

<footer>
    <nav class='clearfix'>
    <font color=white align='center'>FOOTER</font>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

I've created a plunk where you can see the code working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/iJZSbWYCWGH3NKBzwY7u?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem is another.
If i only add the href it will open a completely new page but what I want is to open the page inside the tag <main>.

Comment: @lungo86 So, what is the problem?

Comment: THe problem is that only adding href=blablabla.php it opens the page completely...but is not what I asked.
I would like to remain on the home page and only the <main> loads the other pagina1.php

Comment: @lungo86 have you tried iframe or by using ajax you can load data from specific page

Comment: yes i tried to use Ajax javascripts but it doesn´t seem working....can you post me some examples?

Comment: You did not mention in your original question you wanted to change the content of a tag :-). I've changed my answer to math the new question. I also created a plunk (live running code) so you can see that it works

Answer (score 0):

you need ajax,
something like this, see http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

```
$("#pagina1, #pagina2").click(function(){
    page = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({url: page + ".php", success: function(result){
        $("main").html(result);
    }});
});
```

Comment: Only one second that I try it.

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn t seem to work.
If I click it remain on the page and the contents of the <main> don t change

Answer (score 0):

Simply  use load function

```
$("#pagina1").click(function(){
        $("main").empty();
        $("main").load(pagina.php);

});
$("#pagina2").click(function(){
        $("main").empty();
        $("main").load(pagina2.php);

});
```

html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div>
   <header>
      <font color=white align='center'>HEADER</font>
      <nav class='clearfix'>
          <ul class='clearfix'>
    <li id='home'>Home</a></li>
    <li id='pagina1'>pagina1</a></li>
    <li id='pagina2'>pagina2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href='#' id='pull'>Menu</a>
      </nav>
   </header>
</div>
<main>
    <h1> Main</h1>
</main>

<footer>
    <nav class='clearfix'>
    <font color=white align='center'>FOOTER</font>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: do I have to leave the href='#' ?